# I have a time in a cell, want to minus 2 hrs and add 2hrs to the time and display in excel

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula

I have a time in a cell, want to minus 2 hrs and add 2hrs to the time and display in excel

Example : 02/08/2020 11:00AM 
So Minus 2hrs and plus 2 hrs next cell must display as 9:00AM-13:00PM

I tried the below formula but displays like 43811.0577893518 - 43811.2244560185
=CONCATENATE(A1-TIME(2,0,0)," ","-"," ",A1+TIME(2,0,0))

Answer (score 2):

Use TEXT to format the output:

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(A1-TIME(2,0,0),"HH:MM AM/PM")," ","-"," ",TEXT(A1+TIME(2,0,0),"HH:MM AM/PM"))
```

[image: .]

Comment: Did not work it shows #Value!. @urdearboys formula worked! Thanks

Comment: Worked Boss, Thanks aton! @Scott Craner

Answer (score 2):

Subtract & add two hours (2/24) to your date

```
=TEXT(A1-(2/24),"hh:mm AM/PM") & " - " & TEXT(A1+(2/24), "hh:mm AM/PM")
```